# how to insert socketio real time data to a dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, socket.io

I am able to connect to API to get real time forex prices by below code:

```
 def on_price_update(msg): 
    response = json.loads(msg)
    print(response)

if sub_response.status_code == 200: 
    sio.on('EUR/USD', on_price_update)
    sio.wait()
```

response as below: 
[image]

But I want to add these data to a dataframe, how to append data to a dataframe each time where there is a response?

Thank you

Comment: How does `msg` or `response` looks like ?

Comment: @AlexandreB. just updated, thanks

Comment: Please do not share it as image but in text format to easily copy/past it.